# Probability in Sum of Independent Random Variables

Tags: probability

I encountered with a problem where $X$ and $Y$ are independent variables and $Z=X+Y$ there is a claim which tells that $p(Z=z | X=x)=p(Y=z-x| X=x)$.

I want to know about the explanation of why $p(Z=z | X=x)=p(Y=z-x| X=x)$ is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essential is that under condition $X=x$ the statements $X+Y=z$ and $x+Y=z$ are equivalent.

That gives the second equality in:$$\Pr(Z=z\mid X=x)=\Pr(X+Y=z\mid X=x)=$$$$\Pr(x+Y=z\mid X=x)=\Pr(Y=z-x\mid X=x)$$